# Smallest pattern for extracting string value using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, extract

I'm trying to instantiate a Regex with the correct pattern for getting only the right value of a string. My text file has:

```
Comment ID : 1234.5
```

and I would like to get the right value as follows:

```
1234.5
```

What would be the correct Regex pattern?

here what I have so far

```
new Regex(@"^Comment ID\s*:\s*(?<comment_id>\w+)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But this brings also the unneeded string *"Comment ID"*

Would be possible to not use the group marker `<comment_id>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(?<=Comment ID :\s*)[^\s]+

Comment: Nice! and this also works: ´new Regex(@"Comment\sID\s:\s(?<comment_id>\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);´

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use group names - but then you will have to reference them by indexes.
If left part of strings cannot contain ":" then the regex can be:

```
^[^:]+:\s*(.*?)\s*$
```

Also, you can use intance String.Split() method:

```
"abc : def".Split(new[] { ':' }, 2)
```

Comment: if you're splitting on a `char` you don't need to put it in an array. Split is variadic for `char`s.

Comment: Matt, not in the overload where you can specify the _count_ argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care whats left of the `:` you can just use:

```
"^.*:\s*(?<comment_id>\w+)"
```

You won't need to use the `RegexOptions` for this one, either, as there's no strings to ignore the case of

Comment: Indeed left part is always fixed (constant words) like "Comment Id". It just like a field name.

Comment: So `.*:` will match everything up to and including the `:`, and will do what you need

Answer (score 0):

Regex you provided `"^Comment ID\s*:\s*(?<comment_id>\w+)"` doesn't match numbers after dot

Try to use this:
 `(?!^Comment ID\s*:\s*)(?<comment_id>\d+\.*\d*)`

Also you can change Comment ID to any words or \w+